# unit test target in typescript project

Tags: typescript, unit-testing

I found that in many typescript projects, the unit-test's target is the `ts` source code, rather than the `js` code built from the `ts` source code.

Most of the time, we should test on what will happen if the user passes a wrong parameter into the functions. For that purpose, we should test on the built `js` code, because the IDE has type assertion for `ts` source code already, we have no chance to pass in a wrong parameter.

Finally, my question is that is there an official guide or a best practice for unit test?

Answer (score -1):

> is there an official guide or a best practice for unit test?

This question is probably out of scope for this site.

> Most of the time, we should test on what will happen if the user
>   passes a wrong parameter into the functions. For that purpose, we
>   should test on the built js code

First, I would disagree with the premise. The only point where you have to worry about what happens if a user passes in a wrong parameter is at the boundaries of your module (where the user would be passing in input).  Any internal classes and functions don't have to worry about this.

Second, if you want to test what happens if the user passes in a wrong parameter you can still do that testing in TypeScript using the `any` type.  For example, if I have a function:

```
function getStringLength(str: string): number {
  if (typeof str !== 'string') {
    return undefined;
  }
  return x.length;
}
```

I could then test it with:

```
it('Should throw an error on a non-string type', () => {
  expect(getStringLength(1 as any)).toBeUndefined();
});
```